# Short permalink to an answer, does not land correctly in incognito

Tags: bug, permalink, short-links

I was sharing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319712/1731459) with my team, and I realized it's not landing at the correct answer if I'm in incognito mode.
But it works correctly otherwise.

Below is the screenshot of where I'm landing.

[image]

If I close the *both* of the pop-ups on the bottom and refresh the page, it will land me on the correct answer.

I can see the same issue in the [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) browser as well even without incognito:

[image]

Safari version: 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)

Chrome version: 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)

[macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) version: 11.4 (20F71)

Comment: I can't reproduce it (I do need to click some popups away in incognito mode ...) It might be helpful to share where you *do* end up.

Comment: @Glorfindel I have updated the Question with a screenshot and my observations.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Edge (+ InPrivate), Firefox (+ Private), or Chrome (+ Incognito), although Chrome incognito seems to make it scroll back up a few lines (but the original answer is targeted and flashes orange and it only goes up a bit).

Comment: No repro for me on Chrome Win10 but/and I observe the same scroll back @hyper-neutrino reported.

Comment: a.) Sort order of the answers might be different if you're logged in vs. logged out (incognito mode always sorts by 'votes' for me)  and b.) Some of the answers on this question are rich in images, especially the one shown in your screenshot. I've noticed before that sometimes (when the internet/page loads are slow) you end up at the wrong part of the page and have to scroll down to find where you want to be, e.g. when moderating flags on image-rich winter-bash posts. What's your sort-order when not in incognito mode, and how fast is the page loading for you?

Comment: I can repro this (sort-of, not consequently) by sorting by votes when not in incognito mode either, and slowing down my internet by opening a Teams call... I end up at the same place OP does, because the images load a bit slow, but when they do: They push the post that's linked to 'down' on the page.

Comment: I reproed, the explanation is indeed what Tink says, if there are a lot of images you end up at the wrong place. This has been reported before.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I guess Microsoft is very happy they have build a tool that can assist in stress testing the system ...

Comment: @rene I'm sure it's just my internet connection... not 'the system' :P

Comment: @Rob I wonder why you feel it is incorrect. The issue is in both cases answers with a great amount of images that load to slow, so push the page down after you've reached the answer in question.

Comment: @Luuklag your question doesn't have a specific URL to guarantee that I can reproduce your issue, but I can read that these two are completely different.

Comment: @Rob That's quite the non-answer. What do you read that makes these two 'completely different'? And please don't argue that it's just that this one mentions 'sharing a link to an answer' and Luuklag's post mentions the 'anchor to recent activity'... that doesn't change that the issue to me and Luuklag still looks the same: Once images load you end up higher up on the page than you should. What other difference do you see that makes these two so different?

Comment: @Rob you can go check it on this post: "Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor", I posted an answer there yesterday, clicking that link will end you up somewhere else, if you are sorted by votes, and not activity.

Comment: I can reproduce consistently if I start Chrome , open dev tools and on the Network tab select Throttle: Slow 3G. First load is on the correct position but when the images further up the page gets loaded, the page gets re-rendered and therefore pushed down and the intended anchor eventually is pushed off the page.

Comment: @Tink , Luuk's last activity is shown as a few minutes ago, perhaps they will supply the URL. Apparently your answer, I'm told twice now, is found by "clicking on that link" - so that's the help I've received.

Comment: @Rob you're making less and less sense to me at this point... It's probably time to give up on trying to understand what you're saying for me. With rene's comment from just now, it confirms the issue is indeed the same as the one Luuklag's duplicate is describing, so I'm going to close this. If you do come up with a different way of explaining why this one is 'completely different' from the duplicate, I'll be in [chat].

Comment: I've created an animated GIF to demonstrate the reproduction of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mjYY.gif

Comment: Tink, Assuming that they are identical then complaints that the browser doesn't allocate space for images being loaded and subsequently doesn't position an anchored URL correctly makes both questions off-topic. - Each person is free to review as they feel is correct, and you can override the review if you wish. @rene